# deploy rails app to AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, ssh, capistrano3

Currently, I used capistrano3 to deploy my rails application to AWS by existing ssh key(XXXXX.pem)
Im already done with AWS server set-up (ex: ruby, rails, sqlite3 installation, and ..etc)
However, I met some issues I can not figure out. 
First, I used **$ cap install** to generate deploy.rb ...etc. 
in config/deploy.rb =>

https://github.com/Gtar69/games/blob/master/config/deploy.rb

in config/deploy/staging.rb

https://github.com/Gtar69/games/blob/master/config/deploy/staging.rb

However, when I tried to **$ cap staging deploy** to AWS, it showed

```
INFO[6b5414be] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/GameStore/ on 54.241.249.27
DEBUG[6b5414be] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/GameStore/
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 54.241.249.27: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@54.241.249.27
/home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
/home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/home/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in
```

Can anyone help for it? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

By the error it seems capistrano can't ssh to the server. Did you setup passwordless ssh for the server you're trying to connect to?

Passwordless ssh authentication is [mentioned here in capistrano docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authentication). You can test this really easily by invoking this on the command line:

```
ssh ubuntu@<server_ip>
```

You should be promptly logged to the server (no password prompts or anything). If there are hiccups with that - then I think you should work on fixing this.

Aside from just authentication, capistrano also requires ssh agent forwarding which might be confusing to new users.

To aid this, I've created a [capistrano-ssh-doctor](https://github.com/bruno-/capistrano-ssh-doctor) plugin. It helps with troubleshooting capistrano <-> ssh issues. For output you get a verbose list of which things work and where things seem to get stuck and should be worked out.